# InstallShield 2008 setup will run on Windows Server 2012

Tags: installshield, windows-server-2003, windows-server-2012, installshield-2008

I have InstallShield 2008 project which is for website and database installer currently it is working fine on Windows Server 2003 I would like to run same setup into Windows Server 2012 will it run?

Comment: Most likely, but if you want to make sure, you can test it for free on a 2012 machine, either [locally](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/evalcenter/evaluate-windows-server-2012) or [in Azure](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/free-trial/).

Comment: Have you checked any documentations?

Comment: yes from the installshiled document I checked migration process of installshiled 2008 to 20014. but it it will work without any changes or migration then it would be great. Thanks @JoachimIsaksson

Comment: It should, if it was created due to all recomendations and best practices, but nobody knows what exactly there is. So, only one way is to check it on Windows 2012.

Comment: @BrijeshPandya are you able to execute same setup on windows server 2012? I can execute the setup but facing some issues.